# Access Denied while attempting to put an object into S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-java-sdk

I am trying to refactor some code to allow upload of large images.
Initially, the images were stored in S3 in a lambda function and it worked just fine in PROD. I have extracted that part out of the function now and attempting to do it via the Java SDK for AWS.

This worked fine in the DEV environment because the bucket is public there. When I tested this with PROD settings. I get an access denied error.

The bucket is private in PROD and the user has access to all S3 actions.
I could access the bucket using the AWS CLI but when I try it using the AWS Java SDK I get an 'Access Denied' error. This is the code in Java. I have explicitly set the region just to make sure it was getting the right one, although I know the region is the default region.

```
    BasicAWSCredentials awsCreds = new BasicAWSCredentials(AWS_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_SECRET_KEY);

    AmazonS3 s3client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
        .withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1)
        .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCreds))
        .build();


    String imageS3Url = null;
    ObjectMetadata d = new ObjectMetadata();
    try {
      s3client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(S3_BUCKET_NAME, s3Key, stream, d));
      imageS3Url = "https://s3-"+ S3_REGION_NAME +".amazonaws.com/" + S3_BUCKET_NAME +"/"+ s3Key;

    }catch(Exception ex) {
      log.debug(ex.getMessage());
    }
```

Am I missing any configuration to grant access to AWS java SDK to access the S3 bucket? The AWS Java SDK version is 1.11.411.

Here are the anonymized versions of the bucket and IAM User Policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "PolicyABC”,
    "Statement": [
        {
           "Sid": "Stmt123”,
           "Effect": "Allow",
           "Principal": {
               "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::123456789:user/user-name”
           },
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name”
       }
    ]
}
```

IAM user policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name”,
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*”
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```